# Why I have a lot of errors inside the main method in java

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I'm a beginner with Java and I'm trying to compile this simple class:

```
package com.conto.examples;

public class Conto{

private String Nome;
private double Saldo;

public static void main(String[] args){

public Conto(String Nome, double SaldoIniziale){
this.Nome = Nome;
this.Saldo = SaldoIniziale;
}

public void versamento(double appoggio){
Saldo += appoggio;
}

public boolean prelievo(double appoggio){
if(Saldo<=-1000) return false;
Saldo-=appoggio;
return true;

public double getSaldo(){
return Saldo;
}
public String getNome(){
return Nome;
}

}
}
```

I don't understand why I have a lot of `illegal start of expression` (i think for every string inside the `main method`).

Comment: Because you wrote other method *inside* your `main` method. Java doesn't allow methods in method.

Comment: You're defining methods inside your `main` method, they should be defined **outside** of the main method.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Technically, Java does allow methods inside methods by way of anonymous or local classes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel more precisely: it allows methods inside classes inside methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote all your code inside a `main` method. It looks like your class does not need a main method:

```
public class Conto {

    private String Nome;
    private double Saldo;

    public Conto(String Nome, double SaldoIniziale) {
        this.Nome = Nome;
        this.Saldo = SaldoIniziale;
    }

    public void versamento(double appoggio) {
        Saldo += appoggio;
    }

    public boolean prelievo(double appoggio) {
        if (Saldo <= -1000) return false;
        Saldo -= appoggio;
        return true;
    }

    public double getSaldo() {
        return Saldo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return Nome;
    }

}
```

In another class, or the same, you can use your `Conto` class from a `main` method:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Conto conto = new Conto("someNome", 12);
        conto.versamento(10);
        System.out.println(conto.getSaldo());
  }
```